# R: Generate sine wave with variable frequency

Tags: r, signal-processing, trigonometry

This might be more of a math question than an R question but here it goes...

I'm trying to generate a low frequency oscillator (LFO2) where the frequency is controlled by another low frequency oscillator (LFO1). LFO1 has a frequency of 0.02 Hz while I want LFO2 to have a frequency that oscillates between 0.00 and 0.11 Hz dependent on the output of LFO1.

```
# length in seconds
track_length <- 356
upsample <- 10 # upsample the signal

# LFO rates (Hz)
rate1 <- 0.02
rate2_range <- list(0.00, 0.11)

# make plot of LFO1
x1 <- 1:(track_length*upsample)/upsample
amp <- (rate2_range[[2]] - rate2_range[[1]])/2
y1 <- amp*cos(2*pi*rate1*x1) + amp
plot(x1, y1, type='l')
```

The variable frequency for LFO2 generated by LFO1 looks exactly as I expected.
[image: LFO1 output]

So I go on to make LFO2 using the output of LFO1 like so..

```
# make plot of LFO2
x2 <- x1
y2 <- cos(2*pi*y1*x2)
plot(x2, y2, type='l')
```

[image]

However, the output of LFO2 is not what I expected... It seems to be continuously getting faster and also has some peaks that don't oscillate at the full range. I don't understand this as the only thing I'm adjusting is the frequency and it shouldn't be faster than 0.11 Hz. At first I thought it might be an under sampling issue but I get the same results when upsampling the time series to any degree.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "frequency" of *cos(f(t))* is not *f(t)*.  It's the *derivative* of *f(t)*.
You have:

y<sub>1</sub>(t) = A*cos(2πf<sub>1</sub>t) + A

y<sub>2</sub>(t) = cos(2πy<sub>1</sub>(t))

If the frequency you want is *Acos(2πf<sub>1</sub>t) + A*, then you need to integrate that to get the argument to *cos*:

y<sub>1</sub>(t) = A*sin(2πf<sub>1</sub>t)/2πf<sub>1</sub> + At

y<sub>2</sub>(t) = cos(2πy<sub>1</sub>(t))

In R:

```
# length in seconds
track_length <- 356
upsample <- 10 # upsample the signal

# LFO rates (Hz)
rate1 <- 0.02
rate2_range <- list(0.00, 2)

# make integral of LFO1
x1 <- 1:(track_length*upsample)/upsample
amp <- (rate2_range[[2]] - rate2_range[[1]])/2
y1 <- amp*sin(2*pi*rate1*x1)/(2*pi*rate1) + amp*x1
plot(x1, y1, type='l')

# make plot of LFO2
x2 <- x1
y2 <- cos(2*pi*y1 / upsample)
plot(x2, y2, type='l')
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt,

Are you able to include some code in your answer? I'm not familiar with your nomenclature so having trouble interpreting your answer. is *At* just *A* at the previous time step?

Comment: Also I don't think I was clear enough? I want the frequency of LFO2 to be the variable output of LFO1 (not actually the frequency of LFO1 which is 0.02 Hz). I want the frequency of LFO2 to oscillate between 0.00 and 0.11 Hz like in the first plot. Apologies if this is exactly what you've shown here.

Comment: At some points, LFO2 should not even move at all (i.e. when LFO1 is outputting 0.00).

Comment: Sure.  I don't know R, but I guess I can muddle through

Comment: Thanks so much for this @Matt. This is a lot closer to what I was after! It's still a little different and I'm not sure why. [Have a look at this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rc7oqgzlchnqmvr/LFOs.mov?dl=0), this is exactly what I am trying to replicate (notice the oscillation of the second oscillator is tied to the first).

Again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: That's what you got. Just set the numbers to what you want.  I adjusted the frequency range to make more pleasing plot.

Answer (score 0):

You are not restricting the data by amp as you did at the first plot. So it is normal to see cos output altering around -1 and 1.You need to restrict the formula by the `max(y1)` and `min(y1)`.

So the codes below,

```
y2 <- vector()
amp <- (max(y1) - min(y1))/2
for(i in 1:length(y1)) {

  y2[i] <- amp * cos(2*pi* y1[i] * x2) + amp

 }


plot(x2, y2, type='l',col="blue")
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted")
```

gives this plot,

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I probably wasn't clear enough though. The amplitude of `y2` is not what I'm interested in, for my purposes it's arbitrary. I just want to modulate the frequency of `y2` using the output from `y1`. It should get slower and faster based the oscillation of `y1`.

Comment: At some points, LFO2 should not even move at all (i.e. when LFO1 is outputting 0.00).

Comment: But if you multiply `y1` by `x2` you end up with very different results without any periodic movement. Why don't you just pass `y2 <- cos(2*pi*y1)`. In this setting, the frequency depends on the `y1` input which has a periodic wave.

Comment: Hmmm, that gives me a wave with a regular frequency unfortunately. What I'm after here is a wave that goes *fast*, *slow*, *fast*, *slow* etc. between 0.00 and 0.11 Hz (i.e. *y1*). Does that make sense?

Really appreciate your help by the way. Thank you.