# R: Generating sine wave with a variable frequency does not work as I expect when inverting the frequency range

Tags: r, signal-processing, trigonometry

This question is an extension [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347005/r-generate-sine-wave-with-variable-frequency) but different enough that I think it constitutes it's own post.

I'm generating sine waves that have a variable frequency however I'm a little confused by my results. This first one works as I'd expect and gives me a wave with an increasing frequency.

```
x <- 1:5e+3
f <- x/1e+6
y <- cos(2*pi*f*x)
plot(x, y, type='l', col='darkblue')
```

[image: wave1]

Which is fine. But say I want to do the opposite and plot a wave a a frequency that starts fast but then get's slower. So I do this by inverting the frequency vector like this: `rev(f)`. But the result is not what I expect...

```
y <- cos(2*pi*rev(f)*x)
plot(x, y, type='l', col='darkblue')
```

[image: wave2]

Which is not what I expected. I would have thought reversing the frequency vector would give me a plot exactly the opposite of the previous. I get the plot I want when I also reverse x (`rev(x)`) in the calculation but I don't really understand what's going on. Why does it proceed to go from fast to slow to fast again, and why do we get only half the amplitude in the centre?

I'm sure my understanding is wrong here rather than the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial plot is equal to `cos(x^2 * constant)`.

To reverse it between 1 and 5000, you want `cos((5000-x)^2 * constant)`. The use of `rev(f)` is effectively replacing one of the x terms with `(5000-x)`, but you still have one x term that wasn't reversed, so your formula is effectively showing `cos((5000-x) * x * constant)`.

Compare these to see why that formula yields a different pattern in your cosine frequency than you expected:

What you started with:  [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*x+from+1+to+5000](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*x%20from%201%20to%205000) 
[image]

Reversing only one `x` term: [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(5000-x)*x+from+1+to+5000](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(5000-x)*x%20from%201%20to%205000)

[image]

Correct reversal: [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(5000-x)*(5000-x)+from+1+to+5000](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(5000-x)*(5000-x)%20from%201%20to%205000)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Jon! This makes it extremely clear. If you have time would you be able to extend your answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347005/r-generate-sine-wave-with-variable-frequency) which is the same principle but slightly more complex? I'm still a little stumped about how to go about this one. Otherwise I'll see if I can manage myself.